# Mostrar/Ocultar div

Tags: jquery, html

Tengo dos enlaces uno se llama enlaces y el otro información.
Mi pregunta es, como puedo hacer mediante jquery que cuando pincho en enlaces aparezca un div y que cuando pinche en información el div de enlaces desaparezca y aparezca el div información.

El codigo html es el siguiente

```html
<section class="botones">
    <div class="bloque_btn">
        <div class="btn btn_izq">
            <a href="#">enlaces</a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn_drch">
            <a href="#">información</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div id="bloque_enlaces"></div>
    <div id="bloque_info"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Probaste utilizar alguna libreria o complemento tabs o acordeon ejemplo [bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h) son faciles de usar y no necesitas reinventar la rueda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".btn_izq" ).click(function() {
        $('#bloque_enlaces').show(); 
        $('#bloque_info').hide(); 
    });

    $( ".btn_drch" ).click(function() {
        $('#bloque_info').show(); 
        $('#bloque_enlaces').hide(); 
    });
});
```

Esto cuando clickeas una de las clases, hace que muestre un div y el otro lo oculte :D

Comment: Te dejo estas dos documentaciones para que puedas avanzar sin tanto estancamiento. https://api.jquery.com/click/ y https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show te ayudaran a entender como funciona jquery. Y que bueno que te haya podido ayudar :D

Comment: lo siento, empece ayer en este foro....puedo cambiarlo en algun sitio?

Comment: Fue equivocación tuya? jajajajajaja no importa entonces c:

Comment: @HaileyThc si fuiste tú quien votó en contra, acabo de editar la publicación, así que podrías remover ese voto en contra. Sino, igual puedes votar a favor por esta y cualquier respuesta que consideres que te ayuda :)